# Getting Mac address from Docker Container

Tags: docker, docker-machine

Is it possible to get MAC address of the host machine from Docker container and write it in a text file?

Comment: the container should be isolated from the host, but the container can be started with this info in an environment variable, for example `docker run -e MAC_Host 08002Bdeadbe ...`

Answer (score 8):

```
docker inspect <container name or id> |grep MacAddress|tr -d ' ,"'|sort -u
```

or inside the container:

```
ifconfig -a
```

ifconfig is part of the 'net-tools' linux pkg and this is good way to enter the running container:

```
nsenter -t $(docker inspect --format '{{ .State.Pid }}' <container name or id> ) -m -u -i -n -p -w
```

Comment: This was written before docker exec worked fast enough to be on par with using the nsenter LXC command

Answer (score 6):

Use docker [inspect](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/) to pull MacAddress and redirect the results to a file. For example, try this on a container named *my-container*. This uses range (from the Go [template](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) package) to find MacAddress:

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.MacAddress}}{{end}}' my-container > /path/file.txt
```

If that doesn't work, first try viewing the metadata available for my-container:

```
docker inspect my-container
```

Find MacAddress in those results. Then create a docker inspect command that uses the docker [json](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/#get-a-subsection-in-json-format) template function to pull the value from that specific json path. The path to MacAddress may vary, so here's an example that instead uses Status:

```
docker inspect -f "{{json .State.Health.Status}}" my-container > /path/file.txt
```