# Binding docker image to a specific MAC Address only

Tags: linux, unix, docker, containers

Is it possible I can create a docker image that can be instantiated on a specific Linux machine (binding to a specific HW MAC)?

The goal is to avoid people use the docker image across multiple machines.
Or does USB encryption dongle work for this case?

Answer (score 0):

Docker does not provide a native feature that does that out-of-the box, as far as I know, but:

You can build an image which:

- expects an environment variable `Mac_host` (meaning you have to launch it with `docker run -e MAC_Host 08002Bdeadb`, as suggested in "[Getting Mac address from Docker Container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43275289/6309)")
- will, as part of its background process, test that environment variable value, and exit immediately if it does not match a certain value (or if the environment variable is not set at all)

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47047401/binding-docker-image-to-a-specific-mac-address-only/47049118#comment81049960_47049118) by [thaJeztah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811501/thajeztah), a MAC address can easily be spoofed.

But that same procedure can be applied to a different data: a digital signature that your image would be able to verify through an embedded public key. See "[how digital signature verification process works](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/8034)".

The user would have to pass a message, the same encrypted message, and information about how to verify the signature.
He/she would only be able to do that from the machine with the right `private` key. And the image can then, when starting its main process, perform performs the decrypt operation and compares his output with the original data. If that does not match... it would exit immediately.

The idea is: a private key is... private: only *one* machine should have it. And that would ensure the image can only be run on that unique machine.

Comment: While possible, checking for MAC address would be easy to circumvent, e.g. `docker run --mac-address <something>` allows people to override the mac-address of a container. Protection systems like this are generally broken, so I'm not sure it's possible to fully prevent people from running multiple instances

Comment: Agreed. A better alternative would be to use a public key to check a message signed by a private key that only one machine has: the one allowed to run the image. The signed message would be pass on docker run as an environment variable